# Column variables in Excel?

Tags: excel, variables, formula, excel-formula

Let's say I have column A and Column B. Cells in Column A contain either "Y" or "N". How can I set the value of the cell in the corresponding row in Column B with a formula that detects if the cell's value = "N"?

Not new to programming logic but to Excel formulas, thanks for your help.

-Ryan

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(A2="Y", "yes", "no")
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd do something along the lines of:

```
=IF(A1="Y","Yes","No")
```

This would put the word Yes in the cell the formula resides in if the value in cell A1 = Y.
You can then drag that out using the fill handle (little black square in the bottom right corner of the cell) to copy for the rest of the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
=A2="Y"
```

Will evaluate to a boolean TRUE/FALSE